# Ko.bindinghandlers not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I've created a bindingHandler:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.highlight = {
        update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            $(element).fadeTo("fast", 0.03);
            $(element).fadeTo("fast", 1);
            $(element).fadeTo("fast", 0.03);
            $(element).fadeTo("fast", 1);
            $(element).fadeTo("fast", 0.03);
            $(element).fadeTo("fast", 1);
            $(element).fadeTo("fast", 0.03);
            $(element).fadeTo("fast", 1);
        }
};
```

...and bound it to an observableArray:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: contactsInfrastructure">
                <div class="contact" data-bind="highlight: Contact">
                    <div class="contactAvailability">
                        <div class="contactAvailabilityColor" data-bind="css: "availabilityCssClass"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="contactName" ><span data-bind="text: name"</span></div>
                    <!-- <div class="contactNote ellipseText" data-bind="text: group"></div> -->
                </div>
            </div>
```

It works fine in Firefox, but in Chrome this error is returned: Uncaught ReferenceError:

```
Unable to parse bindings.
Bindings value: highlight: Contact
Message: Contact is not defined
```

At first I thought it was caused by the DOM not being ready, but that is not the case.

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `Contact` supposed to be an element of the `contactsInfrastructure` array? Because, if so, you should be using `<div class="contact" data-bind="highlight: $data">` instead.

Answer (score 1):

When you use contact without any quotes, Knockout searches for an observable with the name  `Contact`. However, there is no such Observable in your ViewModel.

It seems you also did not use this word in your custom handler. If you need to pass this word into your handler as text, you can wrap it inside quotes => 'Contact'

```
<div class="contact" data-bind="highlight: 'Contact'"> 
OR
<div class="contact" data-bind="highlight: true">
```

Answer (score 0):

while binding in html the entity names has to be in camelcase with respect to the column name/entityName.